# Merging two hashes with the mean values of each key if both hashes exist

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, hash-map, null

There are two methods, `hash1` and `hash2`, that return hashes or `nil`. The hashes have the same keys. I want to merge them with their mean value only if both methods have hashes.

(I added `Array#mean` to calculate the average value of an array).

```
def merged_hashes
    return if hash1.nil? && hash2.nil?
    return hash2 if hash1.nil?
    return hash1 if hash2.nil?
    hash1.merge(hash2) do |key, v1, v2|
      [v1, v2].compact.mean
    end
end
```

Is there more succinct way to write this?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609036/how-do-i-create-the-intersection-of-two-hashes

Comment: Ah, the hashes have same keys. I added the info in my question.

Comment: You are right. I thought `try` covers that condition, but it isn't. I'll edit the question.

Comment: are you require to retunr `nil` when both hashes are absent?

Comment: Yes, I want to get `nil` value when both are `nil`.

Comment: This seems this kind of code that trying to make more concise only obscures it. A obvious 4-case conditional seems the more clear solution.

Comment: I would recommend making the 2 hashes arguments to `merged_hashes` and renaming the method to something like `merge_hashes`.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do this, but all have two common elements. Firstly, since `hash1` and `hash2` are methods, you want to only call those methods once, which means saving the return values in variables:

```
h1 = hash1
h2 = hash2
```

Secondly, there are four possible courses of action, depending on the values of `h1` and `h2`. You may wish to represent these with a `case` statement:

```
def merged_hashes(hash1,hash2)
  h1 = hash1
  h2 = hash2
  case [h1.is_a?(Hash), h2.is_a?(Hash)]
  when [false, false] then nil
  when [false, true]  then h2
  when [true, false]  then h1
  else compute_avg(h1, h2)
  end
end
```

Note that it is necessary to compute both `h1` and `h2` even if the first one computed is found to not be a hash.

All that remains is to construct the method `compute_avg`. Here are three ways that might be done:

*Merge `h1` and `h2`, using the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.*

```
compute_avg(h1,h2)
  h1.merge(h2) { |_, v1, v2| [v1, v2].compact.mean }
end
```

You used `merge` in this way in your solution.

*Extract values of `h2` and send [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to `h1` to build the desired hash*

```
compute_avg(h1,h2)
  values2 = h2.values
  h1.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v1),h| h[k] = [v1, values2.shift].compact.mean }
end
```

*Extract the values of `h1` and `h2`, compute their averages, element-by-element, then construct the hash to be returned*

```
compute_avg(h1,h2)
  keys = h1.keys
  averages = { h1.values.zip(h2.values).map { |x1,x2| [x1, x2].compact.mean  } }
  keys.zip(averages).to_h
end
```